# What math category would this solution fall under?

Tags: combinatorics, reference-request, book-recommendation

Here is the word problem.

> You are climbing a staircase. It takes n steps to reach the top.
>
> Each time you can either climb 1 or 2 steps. In how many distinct ways can you climb to the top?

So for example, given 10 stairs, how many different ways could there be

What formula can be used to solve this problem?

Also, I would like to know two other things:

1. Category (ex. algebra, algebra II, etc.)
2. Any resources (books, lectures, etc) that I can use to educate myself in questions like this.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Edit - added that I'm looking for the formula that would solve this problem

Comment: Problems like this fall under the Area of Combinatorics, which is basically the art of counting.

Comment: Let the number of single steps taken be $S$ and the number of double steps taken be $D$. Once we know $D$, we know $S$. What are the possible values for $D$? For each of those, how many "times" did it take to reach the top? How many ways are there to arrange the $D$ double steps and $S$ single steps?

Comment: @LurchiDerLurch Specifically recursion

Comment: However, you will learn to solve problems like this in almost any Book about problem solving. To solve this problem, don‘t wait for a formula to jump into your head! Test the simple cases. How many ways are there to climb a stair with 1,2,3,4 and 5 steps? If you try to calculate these numbers, you‘ll realize that you do a lot of work repeatedly, which might give you a hint on how to find the formula. Also, maybe there is a pattern in the numbers you find out.

Comment: I would classify that under "combinatorics".  Agreeing with @LurchiDerLurch

Comment: Since you list "algebra, algebra II, etc." as your "categories" I'm assuming your real question is "what is the name of the class in which I'd learn about this?"  -- If so, then in my experience non-math-majors first encounter such problems in a "Discrete Mathematics" class in the chapter on "Recursion" (though this could certainly differ by location)

Comment: @SergioBost Do you know what Linear Algebra is? If you do, why did you use that tag? If yo don't, why did you use that tag?

Comment: @jjagmath I know what it is (somewhat) and saw it to be a topic close to it. Also didn’t know what else to categorize it as

Comment: @jjagmath that’s why I am on a forum seeking help

Comment: @SergioBost Then try to use the forum correctly. Particularly, tag your questions carefully.

Comment: " I'm sorry, but if you think Linear Algebra is close to this, you don't know what Linear Algebra is."  And......?   The question "What math category would this solution fall under?" makes it clear the OP doesn't know, knows they don't know, and *wants* to know what categories of math there are.  And that is entirely legitimate.  This seems impractically critical and rather nasty.

Comment: As others have said, this is combinatorics. You can learn about this in Niven's *Mathematics of Choice*, which is written for a high school audience.

Comment: For your problem, you can say this. Let $a_n$ be the answer for $n$ steps. Then $a_{10}$ is the number of ways you can do it that end in a single step (which is the same as $a_9$) plus the number of ways you can do it that end in a double step (which is $a_8$). So $a_{10} = a_9 + a_8$. The same argument holds more generally, so $a_n = a_{n-1} + a_{n-2}$. Since $a_1 = 1$ and $a_2 = 2$, this allows you to calculate successive values of $a_n$. Namely, $a_3 = 3, a_4 = 5, a_5 = 8, \dots$. This is the Fibonacci sequence. There is a formula for the terms of the Fibonacci sequence (see Wikipedia).